# How many posts did Sauron write in his blog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, fan-fiction

There used to be a Tolkien fanfiction, in the form of a blog that Sauron was writing, since the beginning of time. [You can find the first twenty entries here](http://saurongorthaur.blogspot.com/). At some point the person who was writing it decided to stop.

How many posts did he write before stopping? The [first 79 are still available on Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019100758/http://www.kunochan.com/sauron/). Did he write more, which Web Archive just didn't catch, or is that all there is?

Comment: Why, that's just precious

Comment: @Valorum Incredible, thank you. I suppose he probably stopped there if that's as high up as the Twitter go... Too bad, that *was* precious. By the way, any idea why the question is controversial? I got 3 downvotes quick as lightning.

Comment: As the Wayback Machine seems not to have a record of posts 27 through 32, **73** is also a possibility. I.e. [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818182026/http://www.sauronsblog.com/?paged=6) goes straight to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130429000815/http://www.sauronsblog.com/?paged=5).

Comment: @Spencer It does have a record, but it's not always straightforward to find it. These posts are [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160618122852/http://www.sauronsblog.com/?cat=4) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160618183627/http://www.sauronsblog.com/?cat=6)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I managed to catch up with the author of Sauron's Blog a few days ago. Firstly, in answer to your specific question, the original blog contained a total of **79** posts, all of which can now be found on the "*complete, re-edited and updated*" blog, along with a new 80th post.

> **https://saurons.home.blog/2019/12/30/1-im-really-getting-tired-of-singing-all-the-time/**

---

You might also be interested to learn that the author's website was subjected to a hack and the posts were thought lost, hence why he stopped writing it. Now that he's had a chance to recover them (via *your* link!), he's recreated the blog and is restarting it where he left off. The original posts can be seen here on the [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161019100758/http://www.kunochan.com/sauron/).

He's also mentioned that he's working on another project, [Kaiju Safety](https://www.amazon.com/kindle-vella/story/B09CK8BLZL), that you might enjoy.

Comment: Wow, now *that* really is precious.

Comment: some things that should not have been forgotten were lost

Comment: @tgdavies - And for two and a half thousand days, the blog passed out of all knowledge...

Comment: a heartwarming story  ;)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - One with a happy ending, no less.

Comment: I find that link to be dead, but this is currently working: https://saurons.home.blog/2019/12/30/1-im-really-getting-tired-of-singing-all-the-time/ I had never heard of this before, but was highly entertained by it. Thank you for this question, without which I would not have looked for it.

Comment: @MichaelFoster - Sadly he seems to have written one more post then stopped again